# Blazor WebAssembly - use SignalR or Controller actions for basic operations?

Tags: signalr, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I normally develop with ASP.NET MVC, but I'm very new to Blazor. I'm creating a new site in Blazor WebAssembly. The very first thing I need to do is create a page with a simple form, that can create or update an item and send it to the server, to be saved in the DB. I can either send the object using SignalR, or use HttpClient to post it to a controller action. What's the best practice here in Blazor Wasm? I was tempted at first to just use SignalR all the time.

I've seen examples of using both, but very little to help decide which to use in what circumstances. [This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262045/is-performance-the-only-reason-not-to-use-signalr-websockets-entirely-in-lieu) was about the most useful thing I could find but it doesn't answer the exact question and it's also not specific to Blazor.

The question is specifically about the simple create update operation, but other pros and cons of both would be very helpful. Is it as simple as "only use SignalR when clients need to listen for messages from the server, to avoid having too many open connections"?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Blazor Server App is based on the SignalR protocol instead of HTTP. SignalR hub, in my opinion, is actually a controller. Note that an authenticated user in your WebAssembly App should also be authenticated by the SignalR hub in order to access assets on the server via the hub...You'll need to annotate the hub class with the Authorize attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it as simple as "only use SignalR when clients need to listen for messages from the server, to avoid having too many open connections"?

Yes, I think it is.  CRUDL operations are transactional and asynchronous.  Do a transaction, wait forever on the user, do another transaction,....  I would always do these through an API Get/Post.

The only time I would consider SignalR is where I'm passing `object` defined objects - such as a `Dictionary<string, object>`.  They are a pain in controller API calls.